# DynamoDB - ScanIndexForward(true/false) return the same

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I used ScanIndexForward: false and didn't get the expected result. So,I changed from false to true, it returned the same as false did.

Comment: Is your index made of a hash and range key ? (if yes dynamodb will order based on the range key)

Comment: It's just a hash key. I need to add range key, right?

Comment: yes correct. you need to recreate the index with a hash key and a range key and dynamodb will order based on the range key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a table and add the primary key, you should add a sort key for the primary key. Or, if you using the index, the index should have a sort key. ScanIndexForward will be sorting records by the sort key.

`Query results are always sorted by the sort key value. If the data type of the sort key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of UTF-8 bytes. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order, set the ScanIndexForward parameter to false.`

You can find more details in the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)